# Using Constants Directly in the Root Signature (directx12)

Tags: directx-12

I am trying to use SetGraphicsRoot32BitConstants. However, the results are different from what I thought. So I wrote a question about the parameters of this function. I want to ask about the 2nd and 4th parameters. In my case, the 3rd parameter is using the vector of #include . From what I understand, the second parameter is the real count of the array of bound constants and the last parameter is the offset into the array of constants. Is that right?

Comment: Your understanding is right about the parameters, so I suspect there's a problem with what you are supplying for the third parameter `const void *pSrcData`.